# Find socket responsible for timeout?

Tags: python, sockets

```
sock1.settimeout(2)
conn.settimeout(1) #conn comes from sock1
except socket.timeout, e:
    print <responsible socket>
```

Is there a way to distinguish the socket responsible for the timeout?
Perhaps I'm doing something wrong if I have two sockets that are timing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there's nothing in the `socket.timeout` exception object that identifies the socket. So you need to keep track of which socket you're reading from, that will be the one that timed out:

```
try:
    cursock = sock1
    data = sock1.recv(bufsize)
    cursock = conn
    data1 = conn.recv(bufsize)
except socket.timeout, e:
    print cursock
```

Or you could wrap `try/except` around each `recv` call. You could put this into a helper function:

```
def try_recv(sock, bufsize, flags=0):
    try:
        return sock.recv(bufsize, flag)
    except socket.timeout, e:
        print sock
```